# TS2345: Argument of type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing

I wrote this test

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <AddButton handleAddCoreTarget={handleAddCoreTarget} />
);
const event = new MouseEvent('click', {});

wrapper.find('button').props().onClick(event);

expect(handleAddCoreTarget).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(handleAddCoreTarget).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, event);
```

But I got this error `TS2345: Argument of type 'MouseEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<{}, MouseEvent>'.`

I guess my type of event is not good but how I could fix it ?